# Filtering set returning function results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm hoping to clarify my understanding of how set returning functions behave behind the scenes in PostgreSQL.

Let's set I have a set returning function called 'a_at_date' which returns:

```
 SELECT * FROM a WHERE date = a_date
```

Where a_date is a function parameter.

If I use this like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_at_date(a_date) 
WHERE other_field = 123
```

Then, for example, can this ever take advantage of an index on [date, other_field] in the same way that this can:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a = a_date AND other_field = 123
```

In other words does a set returning function run in isolation of any outer query and therefore limiting the indexing options?

Comment: You can look at the execution plans.  Not knowing much about Postgres optimization, I would expect the set-returning function to be a "barrier" in terms of optimization.  That is, I would be surprised if outer predicates were passed into the function for optimization purposes.

Comment: Be surprised by PostgreSQL :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, the optimizer has no clue what a function does – the function body is a string that is handled by the *call handler* of the function's procedural language.

The one exception are functions written in `LANGUAGE sql`. If they are simple enough, and inlining them can be proven not to change the semantics of the SQL statement, the query rewriter will inline them.

See the following comment in `backend/optimizer/prep/prepjointree.c`:

```
/*
 * inline_set_returning_functions
 *              Attempt to "inline" set-returning functions in the FROM clause.
 *
 * If an RTE_FUNCTION rtable entry invokes a set-returning function that
 * contains just a simple SELECT, we can convert the rtable entry to an
 * RTE_SUBQUERY entry exposing the SELECT directly.  This is especially
 * useful if the subquery can then be "pulled up" for further optimization,
 * but we do it even if not, to reduce executor overhead.
 *
 * This has to be done before we have started to do any optimization of
 * subqueries, else any such steps wouldn't get applied to subqueries
 * obtained via inlining.  However, we do it after pull_up_sublinks
 * so that we can inline any functions used in SubLink subselects.
 *
 * Like most of the planner, this feels free to scribble on its input data
 * structure.
 */
```

There are also two instructive comments in `inline_set_returning_function` in `backend/optimizer/util/clauses.c`:

```
/*
 * Forget it if the function is not SQL-language or has other showstopper
 * properties.  In particular it mustn't be declared STRICT, since we
 * couldn't enforce that.  It also mustn't be VOLATILE, because that is
 * supposed to cause it to be executed with its own snapshot, rather than
 * sharing the snapshot of the calling query.  (Rechecking proretset is
 * just paranoia.)
 */
```

and

```
/*
 * Make sure the function (still) returns what it's declared to.  This
 * will raise an error if wrong, but that's okay since the function would
 * fail at runtime anyway.  Note that check_sql_fn_retval will also insert
 * RelabelType(s) and/or NULL columns if needed to make the tlist
 * expression(s) match the declared type of the function.
 *
 * If the function returns a composite type, don't inline unless the check
 * shows it's returning a whole tuple result; otherwise what it's
 * returning is a single composite column which is not what we need. (Like
 * check_sql_fn_retval, we deliberately exclude domains over composite
 * here.)
 */
```

Use `EXPLAIN` to see if your function is inlined.

An example where it works:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
   "date" date NOT NULL,
   other_field text NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a_at_date(date)
   RETURNS TABLE ("date" date, other_field text)
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT
   AS 'SELECT "date", other_field FROM a WHERE "date" = $1';

EXPLAIN (VERBOSE, COSTS off)
SELECT *
FROM a_at_date(current_date)
WHERE other_field = 'value';

                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on laurenz.a
   Output: a.date, a.other_field
   Filter: ((a.other_field = 'value'::text) AND (a.date = CURRENT_DATE))
(3 rows)
```